# Selectlist checkbox y texto

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am developing a website with mv5 5, when using select list where I need a checkbox to select the type and a text to put the amount, I can not pass the text, only with the checkbox it works perfect but I do not get the text field to pass it to the controller

I have tried several options but none works

Model:

```
public class TipoRepuesto
{
    [Key]
    public int TipoRepuestoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Repuesto Registrado")]
    public string RepuestosReg { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cantidad")]
    public int? CantidadRepuesto { get; set; }
```

Vista:

```
 <label class="col-md-10 control-label d-inline-block">
     <span class="text-dark">Seleccionar Repuestos</span>
 </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.TRepuestoID)
        {             
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
            <input type="checkbox" name="RepuestosSel" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
            @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <input type="text" name="RepuestosSel" value="@item.Text" class="checkbox-inline" />
            @Html.TextBox(item.Text)                                
            <span>&nbsp&nbsp</span>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Controlador:

//controller Get:// GET: Administrador/FacturaGasto/Create
   `public ActionResult Create() ViewBag.TRepuestoID = new 
    SelectList(db.TipoRepuestos.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.RepuestosReg), 
    "TipoRepuestoID", "RepuestosReg"`

//controller Post://

`public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include =   "Num_FacturaGasto,RUC_Proveedor,Concepto_FacturaGasto,Fecha_FacturaGasto,Importe_FacturaGasto,IGV_FacturaGasto,Total_FacturaGasto,Fecha_PagoGasto," +
            "Observaciones_FacturaGasto,Nom_Proveedor,ImpDetraccionGasto,NetoPago,ProveedorID,MantenimientoID,TipoMantenimientoID,DetraccionGasto,ChkDetraccionGasto," +
            "IGVGasto,VehiculoID,ChkFacturable,ChkFacturado,MonedaID,TipoRepuestoID,RepuestosReg")] FacturaGasto facturaGasto, params string[] RepuestosSel )`

I should pass the selected chekbox to the controller, which if it happens, and at the same time the quantity, I can't do it.
Please some help

Comment: Sorry controller Get:// GET: Administrador/FacturaGasto/Create
        public ActionResult Create()   ViewBag.TRepuestoID = new SelectList(db.TipoRepuestos.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.RepuestosReg), "TipoRepuestoID", "RepuestosReg");

Comment: Click the edit link under your question.